# Intellisense for MDX?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, mdx, olap

I'm beginning to learn MDX and OLAP databases and was wondering if there's an extension for SSMS that anyone knows about to help writing MDX.  Because of some nerve damage to my right hand it wears my right-most two fingers out to hit all the brackets constantly.  I'm learning for something that could recognize the measure groups and dimension names and automatically wrap them in the brakcets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no Intellisense support for MDX in SQL Server 2008 although many people [would like to have it](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/497938/ssms-intellisense-for-mdx) and Google finds very few third-party tools. [MDX Studio](http://www.sqlbi.com/tools/mdx-studio/) is often mentioned very positively and is still available although it's no longer maintained.

According to MSDN, there is [Intellisense for MDX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) in SQL Server 2012.

But I know very little about MDX so hopefully someone with more hands-on experience may have some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll install MDX studio and see how it goes.

Answer (score -1):

You can try a third-party tool MDXHelper (www.mdx-helper.com) which is an IDE to Write, Analyze, Tuning, Debug MDX efficiently, and it has the following 5 keys features:

1.Code auto-completion
2.Code snippet library
3.Measure definition & reassignment formula collection
4.SQL for depended basic measure(s)
5.MDX Profile collection parallel

[MDXHelper](http://www.mdx-helper.com)